# How to read an intranet site using HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, intranet

I am trying to access an intranet site with a format `https://foo` at work using `HttpClient`. I have the below code:

```
var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", 
Convert.ToBase64String (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes    (string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "password"))));   
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;
 var result = await client.GetStringAsync(resourceUri);
```

What do I need to do to make this work? I have also tried encrypting the password using MD5 but no luck. My program quietly exits after the GetStringAsync call so got no result.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is the value of `result`?

Comment: Maybe you need to set your User-Agent to something that looks like a normal browser?

Comment: GetStringAsync call does not return or throw exception so don't know what is going on.

Comment: You might try something like fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to get more info about what's going on.

Comment: One possible tip: Try it synchronous until you get it working, then switch over to async.

Comment: Does that remote site use Windows Authentication through AD or does it use a normal cookie authentication?